# MySQL result outputs the string six times (using Smarty)

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, smarty, smarty3

I am currently using Smarty in integration with PHP, I'm assigning an array which I use at the html page with Smarty:

**main.php**

```
$sa = array();
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `content`");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $sa = $row;
}

$template->assign('content', $sa);
```

**main.html**

```
    {section name=nr loop=$content}
    {$content.text}
    {/section}
```

**text** field in the table equals to "d"

The output is "d d d d d d"

Would appreciate any assistance, thanks!

Comment: What does the `content` table look like?

Comment: ID (int 11) (primary key) (AUTO_INCREMENT)
title (varchar 500) ( latin1_swedish_ci)
text (varchar 5000) ( latin1_swedish_ci)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solution, I have removed the {section} and did this instead since I assigned the array earlier:

```
{$con.text}
```

**Without putting it in {section} tags**.

Hope this helps anyone in the future!